# Heroku: Cant connect to github

Tags: heroku

I had allowed automatic deploys for my heroku app. But for some reasons it didn't deploy the new changes, so I tried re-connecting my github account. And now I can't connect it.
Everytime I try I get this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mBMy.png)
PLS HELP!!

Answer (score 10):

I don't think this is your fault. Heroku can't seem to get my new repository on Github connected either. I keep getting an error claiming `"Item could not be retrieved: Internal Server Error"`

Try pushing the new changes with the heroku CLI

Comment: Well that worked for me but I prefer automatic deploys over manual.
Hope they fix the error soon!

Comment: Can you push source from you github repo using the heroku cli or are you limited to deloying a clone of your heruko source when using the heroku cli?

Comment: You should be able to push changes from your git source using the CLI @Claudijo

Comment: Seems to be the same problem here. Via CLI it works but that's not what most people are looking for.

Comment: https://status.heroku.com/incidents/2413

Comment: Ehhe, how hard would it be for them to put this link in the error message...